# Java Applet.jar blocked by security settings

Tags: java, security, signing

I have a self-signed jar file and want to execute it in the browser.
But I get always one of these errors:
[image: java security settings have prevented this application]
[image: Your security settings have blocked a self-signed application from running]

- In JAVA 1.8 Security settings:

  - Cert added
  - Security on high (lowest possible level)
  - URL on exception list

Any idea? Jar signer verified jar file. 
Thanks!

EDIT: Windows 7. I had a working configuration. After minor code changes and resignign the jar I only updated java to 1.8.

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Comment: @atish looking at the dialog it seems windows

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that u have the latest java Release, because security must comply with the updates on version 7 Update 51
- make sure that ur applet class is at the same folder as ur html file.

-If you still fail you can add the URL exception in control panel> Java control panel "in windows"
as below:

[image]

Go to the Java Control Panel (On Windows Click Start and then Configure Java)
Click on the Security tab
Click on the Edit Site List button
Click Add in the Exception Site List window

Add url to Exception Site list
Click in the empty field under the Location field to enter the URL

Find more at following link :
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml

Comment: Ok , have u tried to make java security to a medium "lower" level?

Comment: These levels are not available for 1.8 configuration pane